# Split list after 2 values in python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, split

Given a list like this:

```
list = ['tree', 'grass', 'banana', 'apple', 'fork', 'spoon', 'dog', 'cat']
```

What would be the best way to go about splitting the list into 2 new lists every 2 values?

Results:

```
list_1 = ['tree', 'grass', 'fork', 'spoon']
list_2 = ['banana', 'apple', 'dog', 'cat']
```

Comment: What should be the behavior if the input list have an odd number of items?

Comment: List will always have even number of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using a list comprehension with index here:

```py
inp = ['tree', 'grass', 'banana', 'apple', 'fork', 'spoon', 'dog', 'cat']
list_1 = [x for ind, x in enumerate(inp) if ind % 4 <= 1]
list_2 = [x for ind, x in enumerate(inp) if ind % 4 > 1]

print(list_1)  # ['tree', 'grass', 'fork', 'spoon']
print(list_2)  # ['banana', 'apple', 'dog', 'cat']
```

Comment: If green checkmark to the left is possible, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Had to still wait 3 minutes! Thank you once again!